# Using `find_all()` to get all tags of a subset of that same tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to find all the `<a>` HTML tags of a specific type from an html doc.

My code:

```
for i in top_url_list:
    r = requests.get(top_url_list[i])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

At this point I need to pull out (with some regex) part of a link in an `href` tag.

The tag looks like this:

```
"<a href="/players/a/abdelal01.html">Alaa Abdelnaby</a>"
```

There are other `<a href...>` tags that don't follow this convention that I don't want to `find_all()` on.

What can I pass `find_all()` to retrieve the right set of `href` tags I need to work on?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Do you mean get all the links from a website? Have you tried `[i.get('href') for i in soup.find_all('a')]`?

Comment: What's the `href` convention that you're looking for?

Comment: @Shrey I'm looking to pull out the 'abdelal01.html' piece from each of the tags that contain that convention.  There are other links on the page that don't follow that convention because they aren't links to player pages, they might be links to team pages and whatnot.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @KevinGuan Basically, but I don't want ALL the links, just the ones that are of the type that contain the string convention of '/players/a/....html'.

Comment: @SamDillard Can you give me examples of other relevant `href` links that follow the convention you're looking for and the website that you're scraping?

Comment: @SamDillard: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Only get the links which like `/players/a/....html`? Or links starts with `/` (not `//` or `http://`)? Or, starts with `/players`? Could you [edit] your question, and add an example about this as Shrey said?

Comment: @Shrey @Kevin Guan Absolutely, sorry about that:

`<a href="/players/a/bryanko01.html">Zaid Abdul-Aziz</a>`

You'll notice that it's the same convention minus the "bryanko" and the actual name in the text section of the tag (the other one was "abdelal").

Those are the only parts of the tag I need.  However, other 'href' tags on the page aren't of this format.  Here's an example of one: 

`<a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=6&amp;day=24">June 24, 1968</a>`


another one that isn't of the same format:


`<a href="/friv/colleges.cgi?college=duke">Duke University</a>`

Comment: @KevinGuan: Your first question is the correct one.  I only want the 'href' tags "like" (the word "like" being similar to its use in SQL) `/players/a/....html`

I hope this is a little clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are other links on the page that don't follow that convention because they aren't links to player pages, they might be links to team pages and whatnot.

I would then check if `href` *starts with* `/players`:

```
for link in soup.select('a[href^="/players"]'):
    print(link["href"])
```

Or, *contains* `players`:

```
for link in soup.select('a[href*=players]'):
    print(link["href"])
```

Since you are interested only in the `html` filename, split by `/` and get the last item:

```
print(link["href"].split("/")[-1])
```

Comment: It's late here but I plan to give this a try tomorrow! Thank you!  I'll mark solved if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Because all you want is a portion of the `href` tag itself, there's no need to use Beautiful Soup or an HTML parser for that matter. This task can be completed with the page source and regular expression alone, which is shown below.

The regular expression matches a string like `abdelal01.html`, which has characters, two numbers, a period, and another set of characters. The expression itself is passed in as the first parameter for the `findall` function, and the second parameter is the page source. This is done by using the `urlopen()` method, calling the `read()` function to get the HTML, and then converting that into a string format for regular expression uses.

The results are shown below - it outputs a list of `href` tags, which you can iterate through and append to the original URL. I hope this helps!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/"
result = re.findall("\/([a-z]+[0-9][0-9]\W[a-z]+)", str(urlopen(url).read()))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['abdelal01.html', 'abdulza01.html', 'abdulka01.html', 'abdulma02.html', 'abdulta01.html', 'abdursh01.html', 'abernto01.html', 'able
fo01.html', 'abramjo01.html', 'ackeral01.html', 'ackerdo01.html', 'acresma01.html', 'actonbu01.html', 'acyqu01.html', 'adamsal01.htm
l', 'adamsdo01.html', 'adamsge01.html', 'adamsha01.html', 'adamsjo01.html'...]
```

Comment: This is SOOO close to what I'm looking for.  The difference is, instead of getting the actual text of the tag (aka, the players' names), I actually want the `abdelal01.html` portion.  The reason being is I'm appending that portion to the url to create a list of each players' individual url (which contains tons of statistics).

Comment: @SamDillard Do you eventually want something like: `[("Alaa Abdelnaby","http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01.html")]`? If so, I can adjust the post accordingly.

Comment: In the loop, I just want to return the html file name in the url.  That way I can append to `http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/` with each name of those files.  That will give me a list of the full urls that pertain to each player.  Contained in those urls are the stats I need to eventually download.





I have this function creating the a list of the preceding portion of the urls I will be appending to:

`def top_url_list(letters):
 top_url_list = []
 for letter in letters:
  top_url_list.append("http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/%s" % letter)
 return top_url_list`

Comment: @SamDillard Updated! Let me know if there's anything I should change.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful and perfect in every way.  Thanks!  I have learned something here.

Comment: One thing I learned is that I'm not as comfortable with regex as I originally thought :)